# How to make a select element with different values then text using Knockout.JS

Tags: select, knockout.js

I understand that

```
<p>Destination country: <select data-bind="options: availableCountries"></select></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']) // These are the initial options
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

will create a select element like:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries">
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
</select>
```

but what if I want it to be like:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries">
    <option value="1">France</option>
    <option value="2">Germany</option>
    <option value="3">Spain</option>
</select>
```

what would be my code?

I know I can use optionsText to fill the options, but optionsValue doesn't seem to work for me

cheers,
Daniël

Comment: This is covered rather well in their documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I didn't understand the example they gave, and didn't get it to work, I'll work on the answer RP Niemeyer gave

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would want to map your array `['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']` to a structure that would have separate properties for `value` and `text`.

For example,

```
[
   { value: 1, name: 'France' }, 
   { value: 2, name: 'Germany' }, 
   { value: 3, name: 'Spain' }
]
```

Then, you can bind against it like:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value'"></select>
```

Comment: got it working, thank `<p>Destination country: <select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'value'"></select></p>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
 var options = [
  { value: 1, name: 'France' },
  { value: 2, name: 'Spain' },
  { value: 3, name: 'Germany' }
  ]

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray(options)
    };
     
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>`

Comment: Great answer...!! +1